# Manipulating values in a 3 dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I want to multiply the maximum and minimum values in each row of a 3d array by different numbers i.e I want to multiply the max value by 2 and the minimum value by 0.5 for all the rows in my 3d array

Comment: Sample of what you have tried would be appreciated for helping you out.

Comment: Also, do you want to replace the values in the same array or do you want a separate matrix of only the multiplies values?

Comment: you need to provide code which you have tried so far

Comment: I want to replace the value in the same array

Comment: its actually a black and white image I am trying to add color to using opencv. I believe that if I am able to manipulate the values of each pixel, I would be able to change the color

Comment: for rows in rgb:
    for e in rows:
        np.max(e) * 2
        np.min(e) * 0.5                                                                                                                          i tried using a for loop, but it didnt work